# how to find text ratio in uploaded image

Tags: asp.net, image

I want to find ration of text & image using .net. can any one tell me that is it possible to develop such kind of web-app? if yes then please guide me

To understand question click on below URL [image-text ratio](http://20percentrule.info/)

Comment: That 20% web app does nothing but allow you to state where text is on an image and then does the basic maths to determine the percentage. Do you just want to replicate this or are you looking at automating it? because OCR will not detect all types of text.

Comment: I want to make same web app like 20%. can you give me any reference link which help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break down your requirements.

- Allow user to upload image to your server or download an image from another web server (facebook etc).
- Display selected image.
- Show grid.
- Allow user to select areas on the grid.
- Process selection and produce answer.

I would provide the grid and selection functionality in JQuery then upload the selection in JSON to a web service that would do the simple calculation and return the result. JQuery would then update the DOM and show the answer.